# How to extract number from value with commas

Tags: regex, swift

I'm attempting to extract population from a JSON response from Wikipedia. Here's an example string...

```
population_estimate=123,456,789<ref> {{ cite...
```

...but I'm running into issues due to the commas. Specifically, I'd like to extract the number *after* the `=`, but the commas are throwing me off. I had originally had an expression that gets everything until `<ref>` but sometimes that part doesn't appear within the string.

Comment: What about [`(?<==)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*`](https://regex101.com/r/tymCnH/1) or [`(?<=\bpopulation_estimate=)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*`](https://regex101.com/r/tymCnH/2)?

Comment: Maybe [`(?<=population_estimate=)[0-9,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/pKPsZt/1)

Comment: Use this very simple expression: `population_estimate=(\d+,\d+,\d+)`

Comment: @kazbeel That seems to work as long as the population returned is in the millions; anything greater or lesser and it doesn't return the full value.

Comment: @ctwheels Both of those seemed to work and I couldn't find a way to break either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked for me came from @ctwheels:

```
let regexPopulation = "(?<==)\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*"
let extractedPopulation = matches(for: regexPopulation, in: String)
```

Note that I had to add the additional `\` due to Swift syntax. Otherwise Xcode kept returning:

> Invalid escape sequence in literal

Thanks all!